# LINQ stored procedure and return value

Tags: .net, sql-server, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

I have SQL query (stored procedure) and generated method in dataContext.

In my stored procedure, I select 4 rows, but in `ReturnValue` I have "0".

```
(4 row(s) returned)
@RETURN_VALUE = 0
```

Can I return rows? :(

In repository:

```
public IEnumerable<Index_RandomTale> GetRandomTalesForIndex()
{
    return _dataContext.Index_GetRandomTales().ReturnValue as IEnumerable<Index_RandomTale>;
}
```

In my controller:

```
IEnumerable<Index_RandomTale> tales = _dataManager.commonRepository.GetRandomTalesForIndex();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i could be wrong here, but you don't actually want the return value, you just want the function call, so it should be this:

```
public IEnumerable<Index_RandomTale> GetRandomTalesForIndex()
{
    return _dataContext.Index_GetRandomTales() as IEnumerable<Index_RandomTale>;
}
```

Comment: Yeap, just found this answer too.

Comment: One more question. Should i create my ViewModel for mapping result data from SP in LINQ, or as i can see, it was auto created with class name = name of SP?

Comment: yeah, you probably don't need the as `IEnumerable<>` anymore either

Comment: @FSou1, you should probably open another question for this, but it's generally not a good idea to use orm generated classes as your viewmodel due to them having state information attached.

Comment: No-no, not for ViewModel in View- for mapping. I have mistake in upper post.